# Ruby version issue with ttfunk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, asciidoctor

While attempting to install asciidoctor-pdf (`sudo gem install asciidoctor-pdf --pre`) I'm getting the error `ttfunk requires Ruby version ~> 2.1.`

I've attempted to uninstall, reinstall, and update Ruby & Ruby gems multiple times and this message hasn't changed. Current ruby version states it's already at 2.1:

`$ ruby version
   ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For anyone who also has this issue in updating Ruby, I solved it by installing Ruby 2.3 manually following the instructions on https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-ruby23/.